# How to ensure only one DIV remains when javascript is disabled?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a section on my homepage that has 4 different options and changes on refresh. They're all contained in this DIV:

```
<!-- opt 1 -->
<div class="featured-post">
[IMAGE] [COPY]
</div>
<!-- opt 1 ends -->

<!-- opt 2 -->
<div class="featured-post">
[IMAGE] [COPY]
</div>
<!-- opt 2 ends -->
```

etc.

Here's JS:

```
var elems = $("div.featured-post");
if (elems.length) {
var keep = Math.floor(Math.random() * elems.length);
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; ++i) {
if (i !== keep) {
  $(elems[i]).hide();
}
}
}
```

It all works great, but I was just wondering what I need to add to ensure that only the one box shows if the user hasn't got javascript enabled?

Comment: You could acheive this with a no script tag I reckon... https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/noscript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...what I need to add to ensure that only the one box shows if the user hasn't got javascript enabled?

Hide all but one of them in the HTML via `style="display: none"`:

```
<!-- opt 1 -->
<div class="featured-post" style="display: none">
[IMAGE] [COPY]
</div>
<!-- opt 1 ends -->

<!-- opt 2 -->
<div class="featured-post" style="display: none">
[IMAGE] [COPY]
</div>
<!-- opt 2 ends -->

<!-- opt 3 -->
<div class="featured-post">
[IMAGE] [COPY]
</div>
<!-- opt 3 ends -->
```

Then in the JavaScript, ensure that you're showing the one you've selected with the random index and hiding the others:

```
var elems = $("div.featured-post");
if (elems.length) {
    var keep = Math.floor(Math.random() * elems.length);
    elems.each(function(index) {
        $(this).toggle(index == keep);
    });
}
```

---

Side note: You don't need the `elems.length` check. If there aren't any matching elements, because of jQuery's set-based nature and because you're not using `elems.length` for anything where `0` is a problem, nothing bad is going to happen:

```
var elems = $("div.featured-post");
var keep = Math.floor(Math.random() * elems.length);
elems.each(function(index) {
    $(this).toggle(index == keep);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

one possible approach would be the following.

CSS:

```
.featured-post{
   display:block;
}
.no-js .featured-post{
   display:none;
}
.no-js .featured-post:first-child{
   display:block;
}
```

In the CSS you create a "rule" that handles the styling when the no-js class is applied to the dom.

HTML:

```
<body class="no-js">
    <!-- opt 1 -->
       <div class="featured-post">
       [IMAGE] [COPY]
       </div>
    <!-- opt 1 ends -->

    <!-- opt 2 -->
    <div class="featured-post">
       [IMAGE] [COPY]
    </div>
    <!-- opt 2 ends -->
</body>
```

In the HTML you define which wrapping element should have the no-js class per default

JS:

```
document.querySelector('body').attr("class", "");
```

In the JS you simply remove the no-js class from the wrapping element. IF the user has javascript disabled the class WON'T get removed which results in the no-js css class rule to apply and result in your desired output